# How to create a function to open a .fasta file?

Tags: r

I need to create a function so that it asks me for the name of a file in my directory, as well as reading that file. I'm trying the code below but it's not working.

```
function(DNAseq){
    DNASeq <- readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name")
    FASTA <- read.table(DNASeq)
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass `DNAseq` as a parameter to your function, but then overwrite it with the output from `readline`? What error message are you getting? If you provide a fully working code example folks here might be better able to help you. For example, maybe your default parameters to `read.table` are simply wrong? With the example you provided one can't tell, tbh.

Comment: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open connection
Also: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
   could not open file '"multiFASTA.fasta"': Invalid argument

That's the error. 
What I want is a function to open a .txt file, the code I wrote was just a try. DNASeq should be the .txt file I want to open.

Comment: Can you successfully open any one fasta file using code ? Does using `data <- read.table(multiFASTA.fasta)` work ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: And when you enter the filename at the prompt, are you typing it *without* quotation marks (`readline` will assume they are part of the filename if you add them)?

Comment: I was using quotations. Without quotation, I don't get any errors but it hasn't opened the file either.

Comment: Well, in your code example your function isn't returning anything. You could just put `read.table(DNASeq)` into the last line of your function, i.e. without assigning the output of `read.table` to `FASTA`. Does that work?

Comment: Don't include quotations. For example, `readline(prompt="FN:")` and then me typing in `"hello"` (with quotes) returns the string `"\"hello\""`, which is unlikely to work. Perhaps it's a working-directory thing, confirm *inside the function* that `getwd()` returns what you expect it to (i.e., the directory that contains `multiFASTA.fasta`).

Comment: @RolandSeubert it works!! Thank you. Now I'll have to find another way to assign the file, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to use `readLines()` and preprocess it. I also thought it might be cool to allow specifying file names in the arguments to make it more flexible. The `...` allows to pass further arguments to the `readLines()` function, see `help('readLines')`.

```
read.fasta <- function(con=NULL, ...) {
  if (is.null(con)) {
    con <- readline(prompt="Enter .fasta file name: ")
  }
  r <- readLines(con, ...)
  r <- t(matrix(r, 2))
  r <- gsub('>|\\s', '', r)
  return(setNames(r[, 2], r[, 1]))
}
```

#### Usage

```
read.fasta()  ## prompts user
read.fasta('sample.fasta')  ## file name specified, no prompt
# seq0 
# "FQTWEEFSRAAEKLYLADPMKVRVVLKYRHVDGNLCIKVTDDLVCLVYRTDQAQDVKKIEKF" 
# seq1 
# "KYRTWEEFTRAAEKLYQADPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDDVVCLLYRTDQAQDVKKIEKFHSQLMRLMELKVTDNKECLKFKTDQAQEAKKMEKLNNIFFTLM" 
# seq2 
# "EEYQTWEEFARAAEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCMKVTDDAVCLQYKTDQAQDVKKVEKLHGK" 
# seq3 
# "MYQVWEEFSRAVEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDNSVCLQYKTDQAQDVK" 
# seq4 
# "EEFSRAVEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDNSVVSYEMRLFGVQKDNFALEHSLL" 
# seq5 
# "SWEEFAKAAEVLYLEDPMKCRMCTKYRHVDHKLVVKLTDNHTVLKYVTDMAQDVKKIEKLTTLLMR" 
# seq6 
# "FTNWEEFAKAAERLHSANPEKCRFVTKYNHTKGELVLKLTDDVVCLQYSTNQLQDVKKLEKLSSTLLRSI" 
# seq7 
# "SWEEFVERSVQLFRGDPNATRYVMKYRHCEGKLVLKVTDDRECLKFKTDQAQDAKKMEKLNNIFF" 
# seq8 
# "SWDEFVDRSVQLFRADPESTRYVMKYRHCDGKLVLKVTDNKECLKFKTDQAQEAKKMEKLNNIFFTLM" 
# seq9 
# "KNWEDFEIAAENMYMANPQNCRYTMKYVHSKGHILLKMSDNVKCVQYRAENMPDLKK" 
# seq10 
# "FDSWDEFVSKSVELFRNHPDTTRYVVKYRHCEGKLVLKVTDNHECLKFKTDQAQDAKKMEK"
```

---

*Data:*

`sample.fasta`, containing:

```
>seq0
FQTWEEFSRAAEKLYLADPMKVRVVLKYRHVDGNLCIKVTDDLVCLVYRTDQAQDVKKIEKF
>seq1
KYRTWEEFTRAAEKLYQADPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDDVVCLLYRTDQAQDVKKIEKFHSQLMRLME LKVTDNKECLKFKTDQAQEAKKMEKLNNIFFTLM
>seq2
EEYQTWEEFARAAEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCMKVTDDAVCLQYKTDQAQDVKKVEKLHGK
>seq3
MYQVWEEFSRAVEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDNSVCLQYKTDQAQDVK
>seq4
EEFSRAVEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDNSVVSYEMRLFGVQKDNFALEHSLL
>seq5
SWEEFAKAAEVLYLEDPMKCRMCTKYRHVDHKLVVKLTDNHTVLKYVTDMAQDVKKIEKLTTLLMR
>seq6
FTNWEEFAKAAERLHSANPEKCRFVTKYNHTKGELVLKLTDDVVCLQYSTNQLQDVKKLEKLSSTLLRSI
>seq7
SWEEFVERSVQLFRGDPNATRYVMKYRHCEGKLVLKVTDDRECLKFKTDQAQDAKKMEKLNNIFF
>seq8
SWDEFVDRSVQLFRADPESTRYVMKYRHCDGKLVLKVTDNKECLKFKTDQAQEAKKMEKLNNIFFTLM
>seq9
KNWEDFEIAAENMYMANPQNCRYTMKYVHSKGHILLKMSDNVKCVQYRAENMPDLKK
>seq10
```

*(With thanks taken from [there.](http://prodata.swmed.edu/promals/info/fasta_format_file_example.htm))*

Comment: Thank you so much!!